# AJAX JSON response is 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a JSON output on a remote page that looks like this:

```
{"success":true,"content":"some texts goes here, blah blah blha"}
```

I need to get the `content` from the JSON above.

So i did this:

```
    var poutput = $('.legalP');

    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.url-to-page.com',
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data){
             $.each(data, function(pi,item){ 
                 var products = ''+item.content+'';
                 alert(products);      
                 console.log(products);
                 poutput.append(products);                
             });
        },
        error: function(){
            //alert('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
});
```

When i run the code above, I get undefined for the `alert(products);`

Could someone please advise on this?

Comment: Log out data on the first line of the callback and let me know what it returns, - thanks.

Comment: Why are you using [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the JSON return is exactly as above, you dont need to use a $.each iterator on the response from the AJAX call.

You can access the "content" value directly, as the response is a JSON object.

So you can do something like:

```
success: function(data){
           var products = data.content;
           alert(products);
           ...
        }
```